# jQuery scroller simplyScroll slow in IE

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using the [simplyScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/) on my website, and I'm finding that the scroller speed is quite slow on IE by comparing to FF. I have tried to set the speed as below but nothing changed.

```
<ul id="some">
    <li><img src=xxx></li>
    <li><img src=xxx></li>
    <li><img src=xxx></li>
</ul>

$('#some).simplyScroll({speed: 5});
```

I'm looking for another jQuery scroller, could someone suggest some awesome plugin or any simple code for my case?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I'm not quite sure I completely get your question, but if I do, [iScroll](http://www.cubiq.org/iscroll) works.

Just download it (Prefferably iScroll 3) and then use a custom scrollbar (if you want) and use the sideways example as a template. Somehow, I think it even works with JavaScript off! :S